# Linq OData REST API to Query a SharePoint List

Tags: vb.net, linq, sharepoint-2010, odata, service-reference

Hey all I am new at using linq and found a good example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/12/09/getting-started-using-the-odata-rest-api-to-query-a-sharepoint-list.aspx). However, its all in C# and when trying to convert it I get a lot of errors that I can not seem to fix.

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports HelperApp.SPTrackerData
Imports System.Net

Public Class frm_tasks
    Private Sub cmdCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCheckMail.Click
        Dim dc As New TeamSiteDataContext(New Uri("http://intranet/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"))

        dc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

        Dim result = From d In dc.Inventory With { _
                Key.Title = d.Title, _
                Key.Description = d.Description, _
                Key.Cost = d.Cost _
            }
        For Each d As var In result
            Console.WriteLine(d)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I connected my SharePoint to a Service Reference called SPTrackerData as it stated on the website but I can not seem to fix the following:

**TeamSiteDataContext:** I'm not sure where this is in the original code 
      so I really have no idea on where or what to replace it with in my code above.

**The Linq part: (Dim result =...)** I tried my best to form it as i thought it needed to look like but its all wrong.

The one thing that doesn't make since to me is why did I create a service reference and not even use it at all within that code???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TeamSiteDataContext` represents the runtime context of the data service.
When you add a reference to an OData-based service (`listdata.svc`) using Add Service Reference dialog in Visual Studio, a representation of `TeamSiteDataContext` entity container class that inherits from [DataServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) is being generated.

Below is provided the converted to VB.Net example:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim dc As New TeamSiteDataContext(New Uri("http://intranet/_vti_bin/listdata.svc"))
    dc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

    Dim result = From d In dc.Inventory Select New With { _
                       Key .Title = d.Title, _
                       Key .Description = d.Description, _
                       Key .Cost = d.Cost _
                     }
    For Each d In result
        Console.WriteLine(d)
    Next

End Sub
```

### References

[Generating the Data Service Client Library (WCF Data Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd673930%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)